# Proper Manner for Writing COM/ATL Wrapper for 32-bit DLL

Tags: c#, c++, com, 32bit-64bit, atl

I have a question regarding properly writing a COM/ATL wrapper for a 32-bit DLL.

Here's the problem.  As some of my other questions imply, I often have to perform coding work on a large codebase, which includes libraries that are linked from a myraid of different vendors.  We have software which runs on a variety of machines, on a variety of architectures.  This code is primarily written in C#, and C++ DLLs are linked or compiled/linked and subsequently P/Invoked from the C# when necessary (far easier to implement, in my opinion, than managed C++).

Anyway, one such program contains C# code which must interface with several 64-bit DLLs, to which the source is unavailable.  This software's target host machines are all 64-bit.  No problem.  C# running in AnyCPU mode thus is automatically spawned as 64-bit (without WoW), and is able to seamlessly P/Invoke these pre-compiled, 3rd party 64-bit DLLs.

There is one such DLL for which only a 32-bit version is available to me.  There is no way of obtaining a 64-bit version of this DLL.  I have 1.) the 32-bit DLL, a 2.) header file containing function exports (i.e. #define EXP __declspec(dllexport), EXP BOOL       WINAPI  DLL_Function(IN int myInt,OUT int *result);, and 3.) a corresponding 32-bit lib file.

After extensive research, I have learned that, apparently, COM/ATL is the proper way in which to access a 32-bit DLL from a 64-bit process.  Apparently, I spawn up a 32-bit COM process under WoW, and interface with it.  Sounds ok from an architectural standpoint, but I can't find any tutorials or descriptions as to how to specifically do it.  I've tried using Visual Studio 2010's ATL wizard, but am still at a loss as to how to properly do this.  Is there an automated tool?  Any templates or tutorials?  I promise I have scoured the net to the best of my ability, and was just wondering 1.) if I'm approaching this problem in the correct manner, or 2.) do you know of any resources?, or 3.) does anyone have some sort of generic IPC template for this?

From what I've read on SO, it seems like image mismatches like this are a common problem for programmers, yet I haven't been able to find any detailed explanations (or at least pointers to detailed explanations), aside from "use COM/ATL".  One of my previous posts generated a response wherein the questions of P/Invoke signature calls were fleshed out in great detail, which was amazing -- I'm wondering if perhaps we can start a "definitive" 64/32-bit cross-architecture discussion going here!

Thanks!

-Kadaj

Edit:  I am already aware of http://blog.mattmags.com/2007/06/30/accessing-32-bit-dlls-from-64-bit-code/, and understand the architecture, but am wondering about the details of implementation.

Comment: SO is not the right place for discussions.  COM can do this, but it is not the only out-of-process execution option available on Windows.  Using WCF, Remoting, named pipes or sockets are simple solutions in .NET minus the steep learning curve.

Comment: OK... COM is not a good idea, then?  Perhaps I was incorrect in using the word "discussion."  For example, your comment, Hans, is already pointing me in a different direction... almost everything I have read with regard to this problem seems to be geared toward using COM -- I had not considered looking into sockets for this communication.

Answer (score 1):

You can get minimalistic ATL solution in just a few minutes.

Step by step instructions:

1. Create empty solution
2. Add ATL project using Visual Studio Wizard. This would be C++, ATL Project, Executable EXE - you will need EXE because this will be separate 32-bit process hosting your 32-bit code
3. In the project you Add Class, ATL Simple Object, all defaults from there - you will have a class (e.g. CFoo) along with IDispatch-derived interface `IFoo`
4. You add a method to `IFoo` interface, and corresponding implementation in CFoo class, e.g. `CFoo::Bar`
5. C++ part is done, build and make sure it's COM-registered (executable run once with `/regserver` parameter)
6. Add C# project, force its bitness to `x64`, add COM reference to your ATL COM server built at step 5 above
7. Add [STAThread] to your C#  code and call Bar from C# - you're done!

C#:

```
class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        HostLib.Foo foo = new HostLib.Foo();
        foo.Bar();
    }
}
```

C++ IDL:

```
[
    // ...
]
interface IFoo : IDispatch
{
    [id(1)] HRESULT Bar();
};
```

C++:

```
// IFoo
    STDMETHOD(Bar)()
    {
        MessageBox(GetActiveWindow(), _T("Hello, 32-bit World!"),
            _T("Information"), MB_OK);
        return S_OK;
    }
```

64-bit C# code starts 32-bit COM EXE and Bar method is called through.

Source: [Trac](http://www.alax.info/trac/public/browser/trunk/Utilities/Miscellaneous/LowBitnessHost) / [SVN](http://www.alax.info/svn/public/trunk/Utilities/Miscellaneous/LowBitnessHost/).

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately you need to host your 32 bit dll in a 32 bit process, and marshal the data to and from your 64 bit process.

Firstly, I should explain what COM and DCOM are:

### COM

Gives a convention on top of C/C++/VB6/etc which standardises calling and exchanging data with objects via defined interfaces. It also has a registry to load the relevant dll for an object into your process.

### DCOM

Introduces the concept of marshalling and proxies, where you call an interface, but its a proxy which wraps up the parameters shoves them over a named pipe to a different process waits for the results and unpacks the response. The process can be on a different computer and even have a different processor architecture.

So you could use DCOM to sove your problem, but the learning curve it huge, and its almost too powerful for what you want.

You'll need to look at the desired architecture of your application to identify the correct solution, but I'll run through some high-level principals.

If you create a 32 bit .Net process/service to host the DLL, you can then look into one of a number of technologies to perform IPC between your 64bit and 32bit process. You'll need to decide if you want to sporne one per 64 bit process or one per system, and what its lifetime should be. 
Then you need to find a method to exchange data, and marshal the calls.

- **WCF** is probably a good (but complex) bet if you want one host process per machine and have a relatively complex interface.
- **JSON RPC/HTTP** could be another lighter weight solution, you need to take care with security here.
- **STDIO** if you can get away with it, write a 32bit command line application and just pipe data over STDIO, which is simple to secure and has a certain unix like elegance.

The nice thing about these solutions is that you can stay as much as possible in .Net land which will reduce the learning curve.